What is the size of a clam shell drag rudder compared to a conventional rudder?
What is the size of a clam shell drag rudder compared to a conventional rudder?
This is for a ga aircraft.

Not sure I understand your question, but wouldn't the answer depend on the specific dimensions of the aircraft? The effectiveness of both conventional and clam shell drag rudder depends largely on the arm length. Thus, the distance of the tail from the centre of gravity or the distance of the clam shell rudder from the centre of gravity is very much driving the effectiveness. For a long tail, small span aircraft the answer will be different than for a short tail / wide span aircraft.
